# The tables shown in the administrative page are not rendered correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, moderator-tools

Using Safari 5.1.4 on Mac OS X 10.7.3, with revision 2012.3.21.1780 of Stack Exchange software, the tables shown in the administration pages, for example [in this page](http://goo.gl/zpUrC), are not rendered side to side, but one is rendered at the right of the other one, and after the first one.

[image: screenshot]

The same doesn't happen on Firefox 11.0, where the tables are shown one to the side of the other. On Google Chrome 18, the table is shown as in Safari 5.1.4, even with revision 2012.3.31.2006 of Stack Exchange software.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has been fixed with Safari 5.1.5. Now what I see is the following. (The screenshot just shows part of the page.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yay for Safari 5.1.5!  I was about to fix this, too.

Comment: Nooo! Borked in Chrome 18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this issue in the current build of our network sites. If it remains an issue please let me know.